# What are the implications of changing a bundle identifier, and will it achieve what I want?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, single-sign-on

I want to store some keychain information (credentials and one or two details), and [ACSimpleKeychain](https://github.com/alexchugunov/ACSimpleKeychain) was recommended to me as a simple implementation that would be easy to use.

Furthermore, I would like several apps in a family to be able to use the same credentials: it's a nice-to-have and not a necessity, but I would like to store keychain information securely and have several almost-isomorphic apps aware of the same information.

I see that the .plist file includes com.foo.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}, and was wondering two things:

First, if I set all apps' bundle identifier to com.foo.common, will this put them on the same page as far as keychain credentials?

Second, is such a replacement, meaning non-unique bundle identifiers, risky territory or bad engineering?

Storing credentials securely is what I most need and I believe that [ACSimpleKeychain](https://github.com/alexchugunov/ACSimpleKeychain) will do what I want.

The nice-to-have I am looking forward is having all the com.foo.* be able to opt-in (or be automatically assigned) to share credentials so users only have to enter data once.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle identifier is the only item in a bundle that **uniquely** identifies the application and it's likely that problems may occur if it is not unique.

Also, your applications will not be allowed to go in the App Store without unique bundle identifiers as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066435/bundle-identifier-ios-provisioning-portal).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I went by the nickname Merlin when I was younger. There's a place for Merlin in some of what I wrote: http://jonathanscorner.com/hideous-strength/ . You may need to scroll a bit before it gets interesting. (Thanks again)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's a great domain name jonathanscorner.com !